# Ho do I get to know whether specific app is installed on user device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity

My goal is to create custom `UIActivities` for `Google+`, `Pinterest` and `LinkedIn` for social share. And my custom activities should appear in `UIActivityViewController` only if native apps are absent (aren't installed - means native share won't appear in UIActivityViewController).

But I don't know how to check whether these apps are installed
Is there any possibilities for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to know the `URL Scheme` to access the app by `canOpenURL` like:

```
NSURL *likedInURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"linkedin://profile?id=[id]"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: likedInURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: likedInURL];
} else {
    // There is no app installed
}
```

Take a look here for more schemes: http://pureoxygenlabs.com/10-app-url-schemes-for-marketers/

I hope this can help you.